# Trying to get the id of a voice channel without using a user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want my bot to leave vc even if the user is not present in the VC. This requires fetching the id but this is where I have a problem. Every time I try to get the id I get the error below!

```
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
const voiceid = voiceChannel.id;
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(voiceid);
```

Error: `Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Comment: It probably is null because there is no user present, you will have to know the ID in advance (or collect it whilst there is a user in it)

Comment: Like what @Pentium1080Ti said, it probably says `null` because there is "no user present" or the bot is not in the voice channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voiceChannel` is undefined, thats why there is no id property.
in code added if message member voice channel is undefined then return message to channel

```js
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("No Voice Channel!")
const voiceid = voiceChannel.id;
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(voiceid);
```